# Potential leak IPhone App

Tags: objective-c

```
HarrisAnnotation *harrisAnnotation = [[HarrisAnnotation alloc] init];

[self.mapAnnotations insertObject:harrisAnnotation atIndex:0];

[harrisAnnotation release];
```

Running analyze on project show

> Potential leak of an object

for

```
harrisAnnotation
```

Comment: Use ARC and let the compiler take care of the retains/releases. Oh, did you click on the analyzer icons to see the path of the leak?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm not used to using Xcode.  It was the line below.